# Postgresql migration (from local machine to digital ocean)

Tags: django, postgresql, vps

I want to move my local Postgresql database (preloaded with data) into my digitalocean droplet.

2 challenges I'm facing:

1. the /data/base/25760 is the folder with my data, do I SCP this directly into Digital Ocean Root/home/django/django-project?
2. How do I link the database to the droplet using the settings.py file? I'm getting errors: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "root"

From my search, it looks like users are not advised to load their local databases directly into their VPS, maybe I'm wrong about this.
thanks very much!

Comment: You can't simply copy a file, that's not how databases like Postgres work. You need to expert your data locally and import it to your production db.

Comment: that sounds reasonable; can you give me some direction how this might work specifically?